# SSL Cannot Make A Handshake

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

After strictly following the SSL certificate authority documentation, I'm stumped to solve the reason for this error. When accessing my website via HTTPS Firefox spits out the following error:

```
SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.
(Error code: ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert)
```

I went back and found this in the SSL error log (domain was modified on purpose):

```
[Mon May 09 02:11:05 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate wildcard CommonName (CN) `*.domain.com' does NOT match server name!?
```

Where is the server name defined? I can't find a reasonable explanation in my httpd-ssl.conf file to solve this error. Thanks for your help!

*Update* Finally solved the problem, detailed below:

Unfortunately it was created by a default value in my Apache distribution. The option:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
```

Actually needed to be set as:

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
```

I'm not issuing client certs just yet. However credit is due to the answers for narrowing the problem. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes, I created my own certificate authority to do the job. This is something I'll need for the long-term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line in your logfile might matter later, but it's only a [warn] and it's not what handshake_failure means.  Handshake_failure means that a cipher suite could not be negotiated -- no cipher suite is supported by both client and server.  Look at what ciphers are supported by your server.

Edit: I always forget that if a client fails to provide a required certificate, that also results in handshake_failure (section 7.4.6).

Comment: Ok finally got it, this was key (no pun intended) to narrowing the issue. I appreciate the help.

Comment: In that case you really should accept the answer. Once you gathered a couple of question, the percentage of accepted answers will get displayed next to your username, and if it is to low, people will be reluctant to answer.

Answer (score 2):

SSL compares the CommonName with the name of the server you actually try to connect to.

Possibly you are using an alternative name like 'localhost' or an IP Adress.

Comment: I've done a search and ensured that all server names read "domain.com". Also tried "*.domain.com" and unfortunately it still persists. This was in Apache's httpd.conf files. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not .domain.com doesn't sound like a legal domain name to me. domain.com doesn't match the pattern (if it is to be taken literaly). Can you change the names to www.domain.com or similar?

Comment: yep servername changed to www.domain.com with no connection. however, SSL did not log the error this time. it's now just refusing a handshake. are there any special values Apache needs for a certificate authority? thanks!

Comment: I used Fiddler to decrypt and intercept the traffic. I am updating the question with Fiddler's response.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem, and unfortunately it was created by a default value in my Apache distribution. The option:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
```

Actually needed to be set as:

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
```

I'm not issuing client certs just yet. However credit is due to the answers for narrowing the problem. I appreciate the help!